# Focus Cursor on HTML create, then move cursor across property fields in Lightswitch 2013

Tags: javascript, html, lightswitch-2013

I have a requirement to focus a cursor on a particular contentItem property field in Lightswitch HTML - and then have the cursor move to the next of 4 'fields' when a value is entered.

The value will be coming from a bar-code scanner on each field. I am not sure if the scanner has a 'keyup' function, or if this can be done simply when the field has a value of string length of say, 2 or more. The default value for these fields is the character 0, but that could be changed if need be.

This code sample works for focusing the cursor on the *StrSerialNumber* property when the *AddEditHoldingInventory* screen is created...

```
myapp.AddEditHoldingInventory.StrSerialNumber_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
// Write code here.
$firstTextBox = $("input", $(element));
setTimeout(function () {
    $firstTextBox.focus();
}, 1);
```

I am just not sure how to move its focus to the next desired property once a value is put into this first field.

Any advice much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: oninput, check str length, change focus.

Comment: Thanks a lot for assisting. Would you be able to provide a code sample for those? I apologize, I am not a programmer but am learning as I go with this project. I am working from here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp and will be trying to get this right in the meantime...

Comment: I will try to do this will the bar-code scanner itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try navigating this issue with a bar-code scanner itself. It should have a 'tab' over or down feature. Thank you!

Comment: this is possible :) I altered the table functionality slightly to enable me to tab through it, and programmed a WASP barcode scanner to tab at the end.. I imagine you will be able to auto focus to a particular field after it has been created